# How to make null values in the first row of a dataframe take value using the interpolate method?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, interpolation

I have this `pyspark dataframe`:

| time | humedad_3 | presion_4 | temperatura_1 | temperatura_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-26 10:00:00 | NULL | 200 | 100 | 200 |
| 2023-12-26 11:00:00 | 90 | NULL | 150 | NULL |
| 2023-12-26 12:00:00 | 80 | NULL | 160 | 120 |
| 2023-12-26 13:00:00 | 70 | 320 | 170 | NULL |
| 2023-12-26 14:00:00 | 60 | 400 | NULL | 100 |

I need to change the null values of the numeric columns to interpolated values. For that I found this solution:

```
    pandas_df = p_pivot_df.toPandas()
    columns_to_interpolate = pandas_df.columns.difference(['time'])
    pandas_df[columns_to_interpolate] = pandas_df[columns_to_interpolate].interpolate(method = 'linear')
    pandas_df.head()
```

| time | humedad_3 | presion_4 | temperatura_1 | temperatura_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-26 10:00:00 | NULL | 200 | 100 | 200 |
| 2023-12-26 11:00:00 | 90 | 240 | 150 | 160 |
| 2023-12-26 12:00:00 | 80 | 280 | 160 | 120 |
| 2023-12-26 13:00:00 | 70 | 320 | 170 | 110 |
| 2023-12-26 14:00:00 | 60 | 400 | 170 | 100 |

As you can see all the **NULL** values have been interpolated correctly, except the **NULL** value of the **humedad_3** column. I think it is because it is in the first row of the dataframe.

How can I get the interpolate method to modify the NULL value when it is in the first row?

Comment: You can add `limit_direction='both'` to `interpolate` function but this will fill with 90.  I am not sure if you are expecting 100.  If it is not desired outcome, search for "extrapolate".  That is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed, do you know if it is possible to use another interpolation method? I would like to use others and compare the results, but on the web they only put linear.

Comment: check the available method here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Comment: Thanks again. I was looking in [PySpark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) and they only say linear method, but in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) they mention many more method.